# npx prisma migrate dev causing Error: P1010: User `docker` was denied access on the database `apisolid.public`

Tags: postgresql, docker, prisma

I am getting this error that not allowing me to run prisma migrate on my rep.

**This is my docker compose**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-solid-pg:
    image: bitnami/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=docker
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=apisolid
```

**my DATABASE_URL** = `"postgresql://docker:docker@localhost:5432/apisolid?schema=public"`

**my docker logs**

```
 ✔ Network api-solid_default           Created                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 ✔ Container api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  Created                                                                                                                   0.0s 
Attaching to api-solid-api-solid-pg-1
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.66 
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.66 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.66 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.67 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.67 
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.68 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.69 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.70 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.71 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.72 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:40.72 INFO  ==> Generating local authentication configuration
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.22 INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.38 INFO  ==> Creating user docker
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.39 INFO  ==> Granting access to "docker" to the database "apisolid"
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.40 INFO  ==> Setting ownership for the 'public' schema database "apisolid" to "docker"
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.41 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.43 INFO  ==> Configuring synchronous_replication
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.44 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.45 INFO  ==> Stopping PostgreSQL...
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | waiting for server to shut down.... done
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | server stopped
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.55 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.56 INFO  ==> Enabling remote connections
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.57 INFO  ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | postgresql 08:22:41.58 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.590 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.596 GMT [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.596 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.596 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.598 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.601 GMT [140] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-10-20 08:22:41 GMT
api-solid-api-solid-pg-1  | 2023-10-20 08:22:41.604 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I am on a macOS system. Any ideas on how could I fix it ? My friend cloned my repository and the code and commands work on his machine, so must be something wrong with mine.

Tried deleting postgresql from my machine but it also didnt work.